# C# ReadAsAsync returning null when Postman returns data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an api, which actually calls another api internally and passes back those results.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
     new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", BearerToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(fullUrlPath);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     return Ok(await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Sheet>());
}
return BadRequest();
```

It hits the `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` and goes into the `ReadAsAsync` method, but the data returns null. I've tested the same in postman and got data. Not sure if it's a syntax I'm missing. The data object was copied from the postman response.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw (not-parsed-as-sheet-object) response your api is getting vs the raw response postman is getting? It would be my first step

Comment: The code you posted is correct. There is nothing in there that would show us a problem. If `ReadAsAsync<Sheet>()` is returning null, then your model is wrong, or the data that's being returned is wrong. You should change it to `ReadAsStringAsync()` and view the JSON-as-a-string in your debugger and make sure it matches your `Sheet` model. I may even go out on a limb and say you aren't adding an `Accept: application/json` header and it's returning XML or something else.

Comment: IsSuccessStatusCode is indicating the http message is receiving a 200 OK statue.   So one of two things is happening 1) There is no Body in the response 2) The body isn't meeting the format of a SHEET.  Usually when Postman works the Request is different in c# from Postman.  The default HTTP Headers in c# are different from Postman.  So you have to make sure you add any HTTP header to your request that are not the same as Postman.  HTTP you send a request and then get back a response.  A bad response is usually due to a bad request.

Comment: Thanks all. It was 2 things. One, needed to add content type app/json, another was I needed to change a property in the sheet object from an int to a long.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem happened to me once,

I found this is cause by **NewtonSoft.Json** not working as expected. When deserialization, It cannot match to the correct Json Property, which probly caused receving a null content.

If facing the problem, you can first check the status code and print the output as string to see whether it has the content,

`var res = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

if the content seem right it probly caused by unsuccessful deserailization.

If you are facing the same problem as metioned above, the solution is simple:

Use: `using Newtonsoft.Json;` `JsonProperty(PropertyName = "your_property")` (I forget to type `PropertyName =`,might caused the problem)

Or just use dotnet provided `System.Text.Json.Serialization`

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Project.Models;

public class TokenResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue, the reason for my case is that the property is private set. Trying to search the answer from google, but didn't find it. Finally got the answer from ChatGPT~~

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).